# "Enhanced experience except without Ajax navigation features."

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile

I've got a good understanding of regular jQuery and AJAX in desktop browsers.

I'm developing my first mobile site using jQuery Mobile 1.0. I was going through the [Mobile Graded Browser Support](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) and noticed a few devices listed under "Enhanced experience except without Ajax navigation features."

Can someone shed some light on what that means exactly?

- Will I still be able to make $.ajax() calls to the server?
- Can I still use the "hashchange" event?
- Can I still link to anchors on the same page with links to "#anchor-name"?

I'm planning on using the [Multi-Page Template](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html) and the client has specifically asked about BlackBerry support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to use $.ajax() and haschange events only on Blackebrry 6.0 devices (Torch). On older devices with 5.0 firmware jQuery mobile's UI widgets are essentially unusable - quite sluggish. For our application that is deployed on 9900 and 9700 devices we have taken a route to do custom development. You might be able to use jQuery core though.

Comment: thanks, so I should pretty much just tell them it will only work on new Blackberrys? (I'm not gonna get into custom development just for this project.)

Comment: @Greg Don't take my word for it. Grab your target phones and test various [widgets](http://jquerymobile.com/test/) for UI and UI Experience. Perhaps you might not need all the widgets and those that you need might serve your purpose reasonably well and you can claim to support more phones (and $$$) -:)